# Moreover between commas

Tags: adverbs, commas, conjunctions

While writing, I am often tempted to write sentences as:

> It is, moreover, clear that...

or

> We have, in addition, other things to take into account.

Is the use of the conjunctive adverbs and locutions (also `furthermore`, `additionally`, `besides`) allowed between commas, as it is in other languages? Also, does it sound weird or incorrect when found in a written text?

Comment: I'm not sure "allowed" is really the way to look at something like this, since different style guides will make different recommendations. Personally I think the pair of commas is distracting, so I'd get rid of both of them. But in practice I'd be much more likely to move ***moreover*** or ***in addition*** to the front of the sentence and *then* usually put ***one*** comma after it.

Comment: I'd use commas as in your two examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very natural to me when I come across this usage (a comma on both sides of such a word/phrase). Moreover, Google Search supplies a sample sentence in their definition for "[moreover](https://goo.gl/56LJ0M)" that employs the word betwixt two commas; "Lindsey is going to the wedding, and moreover, she'll be singing..." However, I typically place it at the front of the sentence, but that's just preference (or habit). Also see these links confirming this:

[1](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/furthermore). Furthermore: " in some cases it is used in the middle of a sentence."

[2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moreover). Example: "swimming alone is against the rules and, moreover, it's dangerous."

How I would put it in the middle of a sentence would be as you did, without the inclusion of "and", which seems to interrupt the flow somewhat; "the cellar was dark; moreover, mice nested there" ([TheFreeDictionary.com/moreover](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moreover))

Comment: BTW, I like to follow-up a sentence that starts out with "moreover" with a sentence that begins with a homemade synonym, "lessunder", which works like this: "We were already behind schedule. Moreover, the attendant informed us that an unpredicted wind was picking up. Lessunder, rain began to pelt against the windows with such a fervor as to instill incredible anxiety into the majority of those present."

Answer (score 0):

> - Allowed
> - Sound weird
> - Incorrect

The above list comprises the key elements of your question. They will become the basis for my three-part answer.

***ALLOWED***

As we used to say when we were kids, "It's a free world!" Meaning: I don't need someone telling me what to do or that I'm not allowed to do this or that.

Well, it *is* a free world. Consequently, you are free to structure your sentences any way you like. Just be prepared to deal with the consequences if what is allowed turns out to be injudicious.

***SOUND WEIRD***

How weird your sentences may sound is very much audience dependent. Personally, I think the conjunctive adverbs you mentioned (viz., moreover, in addition, furthermore, additionally, and besides) would sound a bit stilted if used in a casual conversation with friends. While defending your dissertation before a group of advisors, however, the words might carry a certain gravitas and formality which would not be out of place.

In fact, audience, occasion, and purpose all determine whether or not a locution sounds weird or not.

***CORRECT***

Your choice of words and the punctuation to go with them is perfectly correct. More important, however, are allowed-ness and weirdness.

***CONCLUSION***

Personally, when I am deciding how I should structure my written sentences, I read them aloud. If they sound "hinky," I simply reword them. Sometimes a *moreover* just sounds better at the head of a sentence. Sometimes it sounds just fine in the middle. Along with how the word order sounds, the biggest factors, I believe, are the audience to, the occasion for, and the purpose of your sentences.